# How to decide foreign key in many to many relationship in Entity Framework Core 7?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi, swagger-ui

I have two tables that are **Dish** table and **Order** table, and try to use Entity Framework Core 7 to implement them in code-first method.
I thought .

**Dish** table is like  :

```
public class Dish
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public string? Name { get; set; }
  public decimal Price { get; set; }
 //define "zero to many"
  public IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

**Order** table is like :

```
public class Order
  {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    [Required]//define "one to many" relation instead of "zero to many"
    public IList<Dish> Dishes { get; set; }
  }
```

After creating these two models and DbContext, I use "dotnet ef migrations add initialCreate & dotnet ef databse update" to create tables in Sqlite successfully.
First of all, I used WebApi to provide "POST" action in **DishController** to create dish record.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Dish>> PostDish(Dish dish)
{
  if (_context.Dishes == null)
  {
    return Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDataContext.Dishes'  is null.");
  }
  _context.Dishes.Add(dish);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

  return CreatedAtAction("GetDish", new { id = dish.Id }, dish); 
}
```

The json request I used in SwaggerUI is

```
{
    "name": "beef noodle",
    "price": 15.75,
    "orders":[]
  }
```

This record is successfully created in **Dish** table, and the new record's id is 1.

However, when I used WebApi to provide "POST" action in **OrderController**, like

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Order>> PostOrder(Order order)
 {
  if (_context.Orders == null)
  {
     return Problem("Entity set 'ApplicationDataContext.Orders'  is null.");
  }
  _context.Orders.Add(order);
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

  return CreatedAtAction("GetOrder", new { id = order.Id }, order);
 }
```

and in SwaggerUI, I tested it with

```json
{
  "totalPrice": 123,
  "dishes": [
    {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "beef noodle",
    "price": 15.75
    }
  ]
```

The error occurred and it shows

```
"order": [
      "The order field is required."
    ]
```

I am so confused right now, about do I define the relation of Dish and Order correctly?
What is the correct way to declare many-to-many relations in Entity Framework Core 7?
Thanks.

Comment: Do your project return 400 error with this message? When you send request, Can the request access into `PostOrder` action or just return this error directly?

Comment: yes, it returns 400 error, and the response is what I described in the articale =>""order": ["The order field is required."]"

Comment: From the error message, It seems the request doesn't bind to the parameter in your action and return directly, The configuration of many-to-many is ok, Refer to [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many).

Answer (score 0):

Try initializing the 'Dishes' property in the constructor using 'new'.
like this:

```
public Order()
{
   Dishes = new List<Dish>();
}
```

Additionally, I usually prefer to define relationships using Fluent API as well. It would look like this:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Order>()
        .HasMany(o => o.Dishes)
        .WithMany(d => d.Orders)
        .UsingEntity(j => j.ToTable("OrderDishes"));

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}
```

Comment: It shows "SQLite Error 19: 'UNIQUE constraint failed: Dishes.Id'.". I have a feeling when posting "Order" data, the Dbcontext also tries to create a new "Dish" record too. That's why DB shows "this dish.id 1" already has been occupied!!